# how to join the results of one hot encoding into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform one-hot encoding in the Census dataset available at:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/census+income

the column that I want to perform ohe is in the country column, so I have made the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

def abrirArchivo(fileR):
    head=["gt lt 50","age","workclass","fnlwgt","edu","edu-num","mar-sta","occ","rela","race","sex","cap-gain","cap-loss","country","hpw"]
    f=pd.read_csv(fileR,sep=',')
    f.columns=head

    ohe=oneHot(f)
    print (ohe)

def oneHot(f):
    f[["country"]]=pd.get_dummies(f[["country"]])
    return f
```

but I got one error that says:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

when I made the Ordinal encoding I have no problem with the following code:

```
pp=preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
f[["country"]]=pp.fit_transform(f[["country"]])
```

What I want is to joint the transformed ohe (dummy variables) to my original panda´s dataframe for using it into a classification model.

Any help?

Comment: `f.join(pd.get_dummies(f["country"]))`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at what [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) returns. Now, try to think if it is possible to fit that into a single column! Not possible, right?

Let me illustrate. Suppose you have a DataFrame

```
   col1  col2  
0     1  name1   
1     2  name2
```

Now, `pd.get_dummies(df['col2'])` returns:

```
     name1  name2
0     0     1
1     1     0
```

which is a DataFrame with *two* columns, one column for each different value in the column `col2`.

If you try to do

```
df['col2'] = pd.get_dummies(df['col2'])
```

you'll basically be trying to fit a DataFrame with two columns in a single column. Not possible! That's what `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` means

---

If you want to get these results back in the `df`, you may use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) or [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). Many different ways (lots of questions about that in SO). An example would be:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['col2'])).drop(columns='col2')
```

*Note: [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) is used to remove the original column.

---

[`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) also has a `columns` parameter which can be used to create dummies *and* remove the original column in one step:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col2'])
```

Notice that the old column name becomes the new column `prefix` separated by `prefix_sep` of underscore (`_`):

```
   col1  col2_name1  col2_name2
0     1           1           0
1     2           0           1
```

Comment: got it! thanks @rafaelc, so I should get rid of the country column and then create a data frame with the values of dummies and join into my original data frame?

Comment: @Little take a look at the last line of code, that may help !

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the result of applying one hot encoding on a column to the rest of the dataframe, so you may try ;

```
f = pd.concat([f, pd.get_dummies(f[["country"]])], axis=1)
```

This will result in the original dataframe with the additional dummy columns, to delete the country column you should add

```
f.drop(labels=["country"], axis=1)
```

Comment: how can I get rid of the country column? because it still appears

Comment: To get rid of the country column you should add f.drop(labels=["country"], axis=1)